USDT ERC20 FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert
I trying to impersonate a whale to send USDT via vm.startPrank(whale1) in Foundry, but got this weird error:
    ├─ [18501] TetherToken::transfer(0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045, 1000000000 [1e9])
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x40ec5B33f54e0E8A33A975908C5BA1c14e5BbbDf, to: 0xd8dA6BF26964aF9D7eEd9e03E53415D37aA96045, value: 1000000000 [1e9])
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert


Actually, USDT is not compatible to standard ERC20 in their transfer, transferFrom, and approve functions!
See USDT deployed contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7#code
function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {...}
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) {...}
function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {...}

Standard ERC20 tokens return a boolean value upon executing transfer, transferFrom, approve, and revert the transaction in case of failure. BUT USDT lacks this crucial feature.
The solution is to use SafeERC20 from Openzeppelin:
import {SafeERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
...
using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
IERC20(usdtAddr).safeTransfer(to, amount);
IERC20(usdtAddr).safeTransferFrom(from, to, amount);
IERC20(usdtAddr).forceApprove(ctrt, amount);
IERC20(usdtAddr).safeDecreaseAllowance(spender, amount);
IERC20(usdtAddr).safeIncreaseAllowance(spender, amount);

Reference: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/trouble-calling-transfer-and-transferform-function-of-usdt-token-from-another-smart-contract-why/39618/2
